# Deviation of light rays in a scalar gravity theory (simple modification of Nordström theory)

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, classical-field-theory

I'm considering a simple scalar theory of gravity in Minkowski spacetime, which isn't exactly the same as the old Nordström theory.  The scalar gravity field $\phi$ and the electromagnetic field $A_a$ Lagrangian is the following (I'm using units such that $c \equiv 1$ and metric signature $\eta = (1, -1, -1, -1)$):
$$\tag{1}
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2 k} \, \eta^{ab} (\partial_a \, \phi)(\partial_b \, \phi) - \frac{1}{4} \, \mathcal{Q}(\phi) F_{ab} \, F^{ab} + \mathscr{L}_{\text{mat}},
$$
where $k = 4 \pi G$ is the gravitation coupling constant and $\mathcal{Q}(\phi)$ is an arbitrary function of $\phi(x)$.  From some arguments that aren't given here, we should use $\mathcal{Q}(\phi) = e^{\phi}$.  In the case of a weak field, we have $\mathcal{Q} \approx 1 + \phi$.  Neglecting the contribution of matter, an arbitrary variation $\delta\phi$ give the following equation for the dynamics of the scalar field:
$$\tag{2}
\square \, \phi = \frac{k}{\mathcal{Q}} \, \frac{d\mathcal{Q}}{d\phi} \, \mathscr{L}_{\text{EM}} = -\, \frac{k}{4} \, e^{\phi} F_{ab} \, F^{ab}.
$$
This is *not* the usual Nordström equation, which uses the **trace** of the energy-momentum tensor (which is 0 for the electromagnetic field).  Here, the electromagnetic field do generate some gravitation (unless $F_{ab} \, F^{ab} = 0$, as is the case for the usual plane wave solution).  So I'm expecting that a light ray may be subject to a deviation, in this scalar field theory, *if* the classical plane wave solution isn't a solution anymore, to the modified Maxwell equation! (see below).  An arbitrary variation $\delta A_a$ of the electromagnetic potential give the following equation:
$$\tag{3}
\partial_a (\mathcal{Q} \, F^{ab}) = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \partial_a  F^{ab} = -\, F^{ab} \, \partial_a \, \phi.
$$
Hence, Maxwell's equation in vacuum is modified by the gravitational potential $\phi$ (there isn't any conflict with gauge invariance and charge conservation).

The usual Lagrangian of a massless particle predicts that there's no light rays bending (but it's not obvious that this Lagrangian should stay the same, with only a new $\mathcal{Q}(\phi)$ factor in it).  I'm getting something like
$$\tag{4}
\frac{d}{d\sigma} \Bigl(\mathcal{Q} \frac{d x^a}{d\sigma} \Bigr) = 0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \mathcal{Q} \, k^a = \text{constant}.
$$
Apparently, this relation implies there should be some redshift, but no deflection.  It's not so obvious that (3) predicts the same (redshift, but no deflection), in the light rays approximation.

So here's the question:  How can we deduce that there shouldn't be any light ray deflection, from equations (2) and (3)?

---

**EDIT:** The ansatz $A_a(x) \approx \varepsilon_a \, e^{i k \cdot x}$ (with the usual constraints $\eta_{ab} \, k^a \, k^b = 0$ and $\eta_{ab} \, k^a \, \varepsilon^b = 0$) give the plane wave field
$$\tag{5}
F_{ab} = \partial_a \, A_b - \partial_b \, A_a \approx i (k_a \, \varepsilon_b - k_b \, \varepsilon_a) \, e^{i k \cdot x}.
$$
This plane wave isn't a solution to the modified Maxwell equation (3) because of the factor $\mathcal{Q}(x) = e^{\phi(x)}$.

Comment: The simplest argument would be that the kinetic term for the Maxwell field is equivalent to $\hat{\eta}^{ac} \hat{\eta}^{bd} F_{ab} F_{cd}$, where $\hat{\eta}^{ac} \equiv e^{\phi/2} \eta^{ac}$.  I think you can then show that light rays will follow the null geodesics of the rescaled metric $\hat{\eta}^{ac}$.  But $\hat{\eta}$ and $\eta$ are related by a conformal transformation, and conformal transformations do not change the null geodesics of a metric.  Thus, the light rays will follow the null geodesics of $\eta^{ac}$.

Comment: But there's some sketchiness to be filled in on the above argument, and this doesn't fulfill the request that it be shown from the equations of motion, so I've only posted the above as a comment rather than an answer.  I'll have to think about this more.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, the null geodesics equation is the same as (4).  It does imply that light rays are straight.  But this isn't the same as solving the modified Maxwell equation in vacuum (equ. (3)).  I suspect that this equation can be solved to find back (4), but I don't see how to prove it without already assuming the result.  Notice that (3) and (4) appear to have the same structure: a derivative of $\mathcal{Q}$ times a "velocity" equal 0.  And the solution has to be consistent with (2) (the "velocity" squared need to vanish).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, and I'm unable to find a scaled metric that would give the same Lagrangian as (1), even when adding the factor $\sqrt{-g}$.  (1) doesn't seem to be equivalent to a metric gravity, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that strictly speaking, a general plane wave will not satisfy the equations of motion.  However, we can show that plane waves *will* approximately travel along null geodesics so long as their wavelengths are much smaller than the scale of variation of the scalar field $\phi$ — the so-called "geometric optics" approximation, which is what we're implicitly using when we say that "light *rays* travel along null geodesics."

To see this, consider an ansatz of the form
$$
A_a = \mathcal{A}_a  e^{i S}
$$
where $\mathcal{A}_a$ and $S$ are both functions of spacetime and the derivatives of $S$ are "large" compared to those of $\mathcal{A}_a$ and of $\phi$.  Plugging this equation into the equation of motion above, imposing the usual gauge condition $\partial_a A^a = 0$, and organizing the terms according to the number of derivatives of $S$ they contain, we get
$$
\left[ - (\partial_a S) (\partial^a S) + i \Box S \right] \mathcal{A}^b + \left[\text{terms containing only one derivative of $S$}\right] + \left[ \text{terms containing no derivatives of $S$} \right] = 0 \tag{1}
$$
Since the leading terms involve two derivatives of $S$, they must be "approximately" zero:
$$
(\partial_a S) (\partial^a S) \approx 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \Box S \approx 0.
$$
These two equations admit local solutions of the form $S = k_a x^a$, with $k_a k^a = 0$, and so solutions that locally look like plane waves are approximate solutions of the equations of motion.  Moreover, generally, we can define $k_a = \partial_a S$;  then we have
$$
0 = \partial_b \left[ (\partial_a S) (\partial^a S) \right] = 2 (\partial^a S) \partial_b \partial_a S = 2 (\partial^a S) \partial_a \partial_b S = 2 k^a \partial_a k_b
$$
and so $k_a$ satisfies the geodesic equation, i.e., light rays travel on null geodesics in this limit;  they are unaffected by the presence of the scalar field.

More precisely, the approximation above means "up to terms of order $\partial_a \mathcal{A}_b$ and $\partial_a \phi$".  All the terms in the second set of square brackets in (1) above will contain one derivative of either $\phi$ or $\mathcal{A}_a$, and the terms in the third set of square brackets will contain two such derivatives.  This implies that the leading order quantity in (1), $- (\partial_a S) (\partial^a S) + i \Box S $, will be of the same order as the derivatives of $\phi$ and $\mathcal{A}_a$.

If this seems suspicious, note that we have to make the same approximation when we try to use Maxwell's equations to prove that light rays follow null geodesics in curved spacetime—which is hopefully a non-controversial statement.  To prove this, we have to work in the limit that the curvature scale of the spacetime is much greater than the wavelength of the light (see, for example, §4.3 of Wald's *General Relativity*.)  Or, to put it another way, the derivatives of the metric and of the polarization & amplitude of the light must be small compared to the derivative of the phase — just like we needed to assume that the derivative of $\phi$ and $\mathcal{A}_a$ had to be "small" here.

Comment: Also, after separating the real and imaginary parts, contracting on $\mathcal{A}_b$ or $\partial_b \, S$ (and some algebraic manipulations), you should get two interesting equations (unless I made a mistake. 
 Here $\mathcal{Q} = e^{\phi}$):$$\tag{1}\mathcal{A}^a \, \partial_a \big( \mathcal{Q} \, (\partial_b \, S)(\partial^b S) \big) = 0,$$ and $$\tag{2}\partial_a \big( \mathcal{Q} \, \mathcal{A}_b \, \mathcal{A}^b \, \partial^a S\big) = 0.$$ Do you confirm these?  Introducing $k_a \equiv \partial_a S$, (1) is consistent with the lightlike condition $k_a \, k^a = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the notes on the equations — I dropped a term from $F^{ab}$ on the LHS of your equation of motion (which was OK because of the gauge condition) but forgot that it still needed to be on the RHS.

Comment: As far as the follow-up equations you've derived, I haven't confirmed them myself but they look plausible.

Comment: @cham: yes, you're correct. I'll try to remember to correct it when I'm at a proper computer tomorrow.

Comment: @Cham:  Yeah, I did the calculation quick & dirty and it seems like I've introduced some errors.  I've edited the answer to be more qualitative while still making the argument I wanted to make

Comment: I think I got it!  If we suppose a wave of approximately constant (or slowly varying) amplitude-polarisation $\mathcal{A}_a$ and a rapidly changing phase $S$, then the modified Maxwell equation says that $k_a\,k^a=0$ (where $k_a\equiv\partial_a S$) and $\partial_a (\mathcal{Q}\,k^a)=0$ (see equations (1) and (2) in my first comment above).  Then $\tilde{k}^a=\mathcal{Q}\,k^a$ is a scaled wave four-vector that satisfies $\partial_a \,\tilde{k}^a=0$.  The solution to this equation compatible with the standard wave (with $\mathcal{Q}=1$) is $\tilde{k}^a =\text{cste}$.  This implies no deflection.

Comment: ... and this result agrees with (4) in my question.

Comment: I added a brief note about the paths of light rays and how they're unaffected by the presence of the scalar field.  Not sure what you mean about the latter equation;  but do feel free to add your own answer if you think there's more to be said!

Comment: What I don’t like of this approximation is that it could throw out the baby with the bath water. I mean, the deviation is already a small effect, and should be calculated from the lowest non-trivial order in the approximation.

Comment: @Cham:  There are techniques, I believe, that allow you to carry things to higher order in the "small derivatives".  See, for example, the [Sommerfield-Runge expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_optics#Sommerfeld–Runge_method) (though that's usually done in the context of a field with time dependence $e^{-i \omega t}$.)  But I'm not an expert in those techniques and doing the full analysis would be too much for an answer here.  Hopefully this answer and my comments give you enough information to make further progress.